# Sorting algorithm help, what Divide and Conquer algorithm is this?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, go

first time poster here.

I was practicing some sorting algorithms in Go-lang. I tried to write a quick sort algorithm. The code can be seen below.

```
func DivideAndConquerSort(newArr []int,descending bool) []int {

    if len(newArr) == 1 || len(newArr) == 0{
        return newArr
    }
    pivotIndex := 0
    leftPivot := []int{}
    rightPivot := []int{}
    centerPivot := []int{}
    for idx1 := 0; idx1<len(newArr); idx1++{
        if newArr[pivotIndex] == newArr[idx1]{
            centerPivot = append(centerPivot,newArr[idx1])
            continue
        }
        
        if descending {
            if newArr[pivotIndex] < newArr[idx1]{
                leftPivot = append(leftPivot,newArr[idx1])
                continue
            }
            if newArr[pivotIndex] > newArr[idx1]{
                rightPivot = append(rightPivot,newArr[idx1])
                continue
            }
        }
        if newArr[pivotIndex] > newArr[idx1]{
            leftPivot = append(leftPivot,newArr[idx1])
            continue
        }
        if newArr[pivotIndex] < newArr[idx1]{
            rightPivot = append(rightPivot,newArr[idx1])
            continue
        }
    }
    leftPivot = DivideAndConquerSort(leftPivot,descending)
    leftPivot = append(leftPivot,centerPivot...)
    
    rightPivot = DivideAndConquerSort(rightPivot,descending)
    
    newArr = append(leftPivot,rightPivot...)
    
    return newArr
}
```

But the more I look at it. It more looks like a Merge Sort..?. I'm not really sure at this point.

I'm referencing the definition and flow of the algorithms from [pediaa.com](https://pediaa.com/what-is-the-difference-between-quicksort-and-merge-sort).

Essentially I thought this is a *Quick Sort* because I'm using *pivot* and comparing them. But strangely I don't think the code did any *swaps* ( which quick sort should do ). With that in mind, I'm inclined to say that it was a *Merge Sort*. But again, I'm not sure, the website doesn't state that Merge uses *pivots*.

Can you guys enlighten me of what kind of sorting algorithm I wrote?. Also, I'm open towards criticism towards how I write my code.

Comment: To me, it looks a (broken) stab at implementing *out-of-place* "quicksort". As presented by Hoare, quicksort is (essentially) an *in-place* procedure - that's where "swap"s are due. Test your code. When it seems to work, consider [Code Review@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: (I think I take back calling it "broken" - by the time "non-`descending`" got handled, I had forgotten *equal* was already done with.) Welcome.

Comment: The pediaa link is full of false truths. And this three-way version of QuickSort with dynamic arrays is completely against the efficiency spirit of QuickSort.

Comment: I've tested the code and it does work. And in an ascending sort comparison between Insertion Sort it generally performs faster. However for some reason when tried it on descending it somehow can be slower than an Insertion Sort ( this is where I realized something is up ). But yeah, anyway, thanks for pointing that out for me.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is essentially a version of quicksort. It picks a pivot, partitions the input array into three groups of items (items smaller than, equal to, and greater than the pivot), then recursively sorts the items that are smaller than and bigger than the pivot.

You’re correct that the algorithm isn’t making any swaps. Unlike a traditional quicksort, which modifies the array in-place, this algorithm creates new arrays to hold the elements that are smaller than, equal to, and bigger than the pivot. That makes it less efficient than a standard quicksort implementation. But in spirit this is indeed a quicksort.

Comment: I see, I suppose I need to implement a swap here and skip where I partition them even more?.

Comment: I’m generally not a fan of this code - it could use some general cleanup. You might be better off finding a different quicksort implementation; I’m sure someone has coded this up in Go. :-)